# Dash launcher without .desktop file

Tags: unity, 16.04, launcher, unity-dash, .desktop

I was testing my application and suddenly I have launcher of this application in my dash. I'm trying delete it but there is no `.desktop` file in `/usr/share/applications` and `.local/share/applications`.

- How can I delete this launcher?
- Is there some register of dash
  launchers?

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.

Thank's for help!

### Edit

Maybe I accidently click to `Add to Dash` option.

### Edit 2

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: When you say Dash, are you referring to the list of applications that comes up when you Click the Ubuntu Button, or are you speaking of the Strip on the left side which is called the Launcher?  Also, what type of application was it that you were testing?  What language was it, `bash` or some other?

Comment: @L.D.James I mean list of applications.

Comment: @L.D.James  It's Java application.

Comment: I believe you are saying what you see when you click on the button on the top left hand corner.  There's also a list of applications that are on the launcher.  That is the strip that is on the left side of the screen.  I can't tell by your message which one you are referring to.  Do you have to click a button before you see the list or is this list always displayed?

Comment: @L.D.James I added a screenshot.

Comment: Looking at your image, you would have had to click to bring that up.  The button you clicked to bring that up is called the Ubuntu Button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a button on the top of the Launcher.  When you hover the mouse over it, it'll say `Search your computer`.  That search area will remember the things that you run and documents that you work with.  Those items will eventually scroll off and be replaced by your more recent activity.

You can remove items from your history by clicking on the Unity Button and typing: `security & privacy` to bring up the tool.

It'll search as you type a key.  You should see it by the second or third key.

If you click the button `Clear Usage Data`, you'll get another menu giving you an option of how much you want to remove.  The menu is:

- **In the past hour**
- **In the past day**
- **In the past week**
- **From - To** (you specify an interval of time)
- **From all time**